# reactjs theme: creative time Material Dashboard 2 React: How to put navlinks in the top

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the free version of creative time Material Dashboard 2 React template. I want to put the navlinks on the top bar. Is it possible

**[image: strong text]**

can someone guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to put the navlinks on the top bar in the Creative Tim Material Dashboard 2 React template. To achieve this, you will need to modify the template's code and CSS. Here's a general guide to help you get started:

1. **Identify the top bar component**: Examine the code of the template to locate the component responsible for rendering the top bar. It might be named something like `TopBar` or `Navbar`.
2. **Inspect the existing structure**: Identify the current structure of the top bar component and determine how the navlinks are currently positioned. Look for any CSS classes or HTML elements that can be modified to achieve the desired layout.
3. **Modify the component**: Based on your findings, update the component code to rearrange the elements and position the navlinks at the desired location on the top bar.
4. **Adjust the CSS**: If necessary, modify the template's CSS to update the styles and positioning of the navlinks. You may need to add custom CSS or override existing classes to achieve the desired appearance.
5. **Test the changes**: Run your application and ensure that the navlinks are now positioned correctly on the top bar. Verify that the functionality of the navlinks is maintained and that the layout is visually appealing.

Please note that the exact steps and code changes needed may vary depending on the specific structure and implementation of the template you are using.